# How to forcefully terminate a converter application process using batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, terminate, kill-process, taskkill

I've been trying to terminate a video converter application process after it run conversions for five seconds (or you could say after a given time). This is the code I've been tying to use,

```
@echo off
TASKLIST
TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
TASKKILL /IM /F /T FileRx.exe
```

But it doesn't kill the process. Can someone shed some light on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful about the order of the `taskkill` switches. Try the following:

```
taskkill.exe /F /IM FileRx.exe /T
```

The process name should be right after /IM. See `taskkill /?` for the examples.

Comment: Does 'taskkill.exe' is important?

Comment: It is a good idea to always include the path and extension, so, ideally `%systemroot%\System32\taskkill.exe`